# Placing Check Box Before Input Field

Tags: extjs

I have Panel with set of fields,Those fields have some bundled validation rules
and other functions like setValue,InitValue etc. Now am trying to insert check box field at the run time, tried with insert add functions of Ext JS,but they are inserting on separate row
of the panel, but I need to insert this checkbox before one of the input field,For that
I have created new panel with new input field and check box and added to parent panel
this works fine from placing check box before input field point of view,But the
problem is input field loosing its native configuration options like setValue,initValue,validator etc.
and throws error,Any suggestion to place check box without harming the input field components.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Ext.form.CompositeField instead of TextField, for instance:

```
    new Ext.form.CompositeField({
        fieldLabel: '...',
        msgTarget : 'side',
        combineErrors: false,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'checkbox'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'textfield'
            }
        ]
    })
```